# How to allow only selected people visit a webpage?

Tags: websites

Simple question,
is there a secure way to make your page require some sort of password? So in practise I'd give someone a password that would allow him to visit my webpage. I need something easy to be able to give someone access just by telling them to do/type something.
Thanks

Comment: If you want something simple use Apache's built in password system. Read apache documentation for implementation.

Comment: Are you really asking if it is possible to have a password protected webpage or some other "secret" thing to make the page only available to a specific user, i.e. something like a private URL only known to he user? If this is the case then yes and you need just look at the zillions of websites which do this and I would be surprised if you never had to login somewhere to access content. As for how to do this - this depends on your unknown setup of the site. If not your question is unclear, at least for me.

Comment: this question should be posted on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Basic authentication** is what you are looking for. Most of the web servers support basic authentication out-of-the-box. It could be that you have to write down the usernames and passwords (mostly hashed) in a file so that it will be read by the server for authentication. You also will have to define which pages (or all pages) should be secured with basic authentication. This is the simplest way for you to achieve what you want in my opinion.

Comment: make sure to use basic auth only over https.